# Excel activex textbox - unable to select for typing

Tags: excel, textbox, activex

Office 365/Excel, I did the following:

1. Open New blank workbook.worksheet
2. Insert activex textbox 3)properties - link to a cell (G1).

But when out of design mode and selecting the textbox to type, the cursor is not showing - that is, no invitation to type anything.  If I type something in G1, that value appears in the textbox. If I type something in the textbox, the characters are invisible in the textbox but appear dynamically in G1, and then appear in the textbox when I click outside the textbox.

Also, if I format textbox to change the order to something else (say "bring to front"), I can type in the textbox OK, but when I click outside, the behaviour returns.

I read somewhere a textbox is bi-directional and this appears to be so, except for being unable to see the characters typed in the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wondering if you're using external monitors?

There seems to be a bug in Excel and I had the exact same issue. As soon as I unplugged the second monitor or (actually just moving the Excel document to the main screen, the ActiveX textbox was working as intended).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was the problem which I discovered for myself. I posted this 7 months ago and you are the only one to respond. Thanks again

Comment: Just had this same problem. Surface Laptop 3 running Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 and Office 365 version 2312 click-to-run, Surface Dock with 2x external monitors. Spent nearly 2 hours trying to figure out why my ActiveX Text field wouldn't allow me to edit, THIS was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:
Just put this in the VBA Code Editor:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus() 
    
TextBox1.BringToFront

TextBox1.Activate

End Sub
```

Remember to check your textbox's name and insert it.